# Click Counter with JS: number of clicks, time and button_id for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have multiple buttons and the output is supposed to contain the time, the button_id and the number of clicks for each button (see below). However, I cannot find a way to implement a working click_counter for each button.

Many thanks,

```
<button type="button" id="button_1" >click 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button_2" >click 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button_3" >click 3</button>
<button type="button" id="button_4" >click 4</button>

<script>

    let count_time = {};

    $('button').click(function (d) {
        d.click_counter = (d.click_counter || 0) + 1;
        let click_time = Date.now();
        count_time[d.target.id] = {
            button_id: d.target.id,
            click_time: click_time,
            click_count: d.click_counter,
        }
        liveSend(count_time[d.target.id])})

</script>
```

Ouput:

{'button_id': 'button_1', 'click_time': 1624600982871, 'click_count': 1}
{'button_id': 'button_1', 'click_time': 1624600983578, **'click_count': 1**}
{'button_id': 'button_2', 'click_time': 1624600984171, 'click_count': 1}
{'button_id': 'button_3', 'click_time': 1624600984683, 'click_count': 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your click_counter in a data-attribute that you can read from and write to each iteration. It will be a string, so you'll need to convert to a number each time.

```js
let count_time = {};

$('button').click(function(d) {
  d.target.dataset.click_counter = (+d.target.dataset.click_counter || 0) + 1; 
  // note the shorthand number conversion by prepending with +
  let click_time = Date.now();
  count_time[d.target.id] = {
    button_id: d.target.id,
    click_time: click_time,
    click_count: d.target.dataset.click_counter,
  }
  console.log(count_time)
 //  liveSend(count_time[d.target.id])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-click_counter id="button_1">click 1</button>
<button type="button" data-click_counter id="button_2">click 2</button>
<button type="button" data-click_counter id="button_3">click 3</button>
<button type="button" data-click_counter id="button_4">click 4</button>
```